# The distance in Riemann manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $f: M\to M$, where $(M,\rho)$ is a closed Riemann manifold, and $(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{\rho})$ is the universal covering of $(M,\rho)$, $D$ is a fundamental domain of $(\widetilde{M},\widetilde{\rho})$. $\widetilde{f}$ is the lift of $f$, we suppose there is $x\in D$ s.t. $\widetilde{f}(x)=x$ then I want to prove that: there exist a constant $C$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $$max\{max_{x\in M}|d_xf^n|,max_{x\in M}|d_xf^{-n}|\} \ge C sup_{z\in D}distance_{\widetilde{\rho}}(x,\widetilde{f}^nz).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $C=1$ and you do not even need to include derivatives of inverse iterations in the left hand side. To prove this just use the definition of the length of the image under f of a geodesic in M connecting projection of x to projection of z.

Comment: Do you mean like this: let $a=\pi(x),b=\pi(z)$,$\gamma(t)$ is a geodesic connecting a and b, then we calculate $\int_0^1 \|(f \gamma)^{'}(t)\|dt$, and how could we continue?

Comment: Now, use definition of the norm of derivative of $f$ and the chain rule.

Comment: $|d_xf|=\sum g^{ij}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$, $|(f\gamma)^{'}|=|\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\gamma^{'}(t)|$, and then?

Comment: Now, use definition of the norm of a linear operator: $|Av|\le ||A|| \cdot |v|$. If $||A||\le C$ then $|Av|\le C|v|$ for all vectors $v$. The linear operator in question is the differential of $f$ at the given point and you use it for vectors $v$ tangent to the geodesic curve. Lastly, integrate the inequality.